# Carousel text alignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web development. 
Currently I'm facing a problem with the text alignment in the carousel.

The JS fiddle is here. http://jsfiddle.net/QYMZb/

The problem with it is that the text would vertically align top first before align center while sliding. I think I'm doing something wrong here.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide"  style="width:400px; height:200px;"> <!-- slider -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators middle">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <div class="carousel-inner row-padded">

                    <div class="item active" style="width:340px; height:120px;">
                        "fdfdsfdsfds fsfsdf sfsdfs fasf sasdfasdf asdfasdf asdfasdfas sdfafs"

                    </div>

                    <div class="item" style="width:340px; height:120px;">
                        " asdfsadfasd fasdfasdfasd fasdfas dfasdfasdf asdfasfdsa"
                    </div>
                    <div class="item" style="width:340px; height:120px;">
                        fsfafdsfas asd fsa f as fas f asdf asdfasdf asdf as fa sdf asf sd asdf asdf asdfa sdf asd f asd sda 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During transition, your new active div.item receives a position absolute from the class prev or next. This class is assigned few seconds.

```
.carousel-inner > .next, .carousel-inner > .prev {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

That is the reason of the problem.

The real problem is that .carousel-inner is not intended to have a padding. To get the padding style you must give the padding to the .carousel or wrap your .carousel-inner inside a padded div.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide row-padded">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QYMZb/6/

Comment: How the heck did you figure that out without his live version? (tempted to post a new question myself on exchange lol).

Comment: it works after applying top:35px, but the transition still not as smooth and some overlapping of text.

Comment: Using firebug I saw some ghost classes being set in for few seconds, I manually put them and found the absolute attribute.

Comment: @user774150 .carousel-inner must not have a padding. Wrap it inside your row-padded class. http://jsfiddle.net/QYMZb/5/